# How do I export variables for all users in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, redhat

I am using Red Hat. I need to export variables for all users (permanently). How would I go about doing that? I know there is a file for a single user where I can set permanent variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put the variable assignments in one of the shell startup scripts:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bash_profile
/etc/bashrc
```

for bash and some other shells, depending on how your particular distro is configured. There are equivalents for most shells.  There is also a file

```
/etc/environment
```

which is not a script but contains enviroment variable assignments, and is loaded at login via pam_env.so.  Obviously this works only on systems that use PAM for authentication (almost all Linux distros, but probably not Solaris).

Comment: Solaris uses PAM; whether it's version of PAM uses `/etc/environment` is a separate issue.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from `/etc/profile`, etc., adding a script into `/etc/profile.d` to achieve your feature is ideal because it works well with packagers which expect to be able to install and uninstall.